# Using embedded attributes in Vuetify Calendar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, calendar, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use the [v-calendar](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars/) component from Vuetify.

I saw in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#props) I can use the `event-start` prop if my events don't have the same attributes' names.

The problem is that my events have embedded attributes and I don't know if `event-start` handles this case.

My events :

```
events: [
      {
        id: 'b9d93291-6d95-47b9-994a-ee9f266fb6b8',
        type: 'reservation_item',
        attributes: {
          start_date: '2020-09-23T00:00:00.000Z',
          end_date: '2020-09-25T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
      },
    ]
```

The events example from vuetify :

```
events: [
      {
        name: 'Weekly Meeting',
        start: '2020-09-07 09:00',
        end: '2020-09-07 10:00',
      },
    ],
```

I tried to do something like that but it doesn't work.

```
<v-calendar
  ref="calendar"
  locale="fr-fr"
  :now="today"
  :value="today"
  :events="events"
  event-start="attributes.start"
  color="primary"
  type="month"
></v-calendar>
```

Comment: `event-start` expects a key `string`. when you provide `event-start="attributes.start"` like this it will not access the property inside of your `attributes: {}` object, instead it search for a key name of `attributes.start` in the event object. in this case you need to move the `start` and `end` dates to the parent level of the event object like in `vuetify` example you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this works, I had to change my `events` data

```
    <template>
      <v-calendar
        ref="calendar"
        locale="fr-fr"
        :events="myEvents"
        event-start="start"
        color="primary"
        type="month"
      ></v-calendar>
    </template>

  data: () => ({
    events: [
      {
        id: 'b9d93291-6d95-47b9-994a-ee9f266fb6b8',
        type: 'reservation_item',
        attributes: {
          start_date: '2020-09-23T00:00:00.000Z',
          end_date: '2020-09-25T00:00:00.000Z',
        },
      },
    ],
  }),
  computed: {
    myEvents() {
      const reservations = this.reservations
      reservations.forEach((element) => {
        element.start = element.attributes.start_date
        element.name = 'test'
        element.end = element.attributes.end_date
      })

      return reservations
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

After spelunking the source code [for the vuetify plugin](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/f055c3627f76fdd9f7b966dd9a6ba1868401a325/packages/vuetify/src/components/VCalendar/util/events.ts#L19), the latter expects that the value be present in the event object, as a direct property. So you cannot acces other nested "children", it has to be a direct property.

There are two alternatives to make this work:

1- map your events array by moving the properties inside `attributes` to the root of your object then pass this prop to `v-calendar` : `event-start="startDate"`

2- Create a javascript class (MyEvent) with a `fromJson` method that take the raw JSON from your API ( this way you encapsulate the JSON into domain objects)  and return an array of MyEvent instances. this way you can do for example : `events[0].start` and you don't even have to pass it as a value to the `event-start` prop, since by default it expects a `start` attribute as a default value.

Another advantage of this alternative, is that since the event is now encapsulated into its own javascript class, you can add helper methods, or getters/setter or any logic that would otherwise be inside your "view" logic, and contribute to have a better separation of concerns.